# the increment of a returned value

Tags: c++

I have defined a function like this:

```
int test(int n) {
    const int b = n;
    return b;
}
```

While in the main function, I use like this:

```
 int temp = test(50)++;
```

And the g++ reports an error:

> error: lvalue required as increment operand

Actually, I'm fully confused by this. Would you like to give me some tips or explain it to me.

Comment: that is equivalent to `int temp = test(50) = test(50) + 1;`, I don't think that is what you want

Comment: you can use int temp = test(50)+1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only apply `++` to an lvalue (at least of built-in type). The return value from a function can be an lvalue *if* if it returns a reference, but otherwise it's an rvalue (in which case, you can't apply `++` to it).

Comment: Well, thank you very much. Does the local const variable 'b' inside the function make an effect on this problem when it is returned by the type of int?

Comment: @JinTsai: No--the fact that `b` is `const` doesn't really mean much here. If it wasn't `const`, you should still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `test` is an `rvalue`. You cannot use the increment operator (`++`) on it. You can change your calling code to:

```
int temp = test(50);
temp++;
```

or

```
int temp = test(50) + 1;
```

Comment: Are you sure its not an rvalue?

Comment: Fixed `lvalue` -> `rvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

Once constant value get intialised you cant not change that value.So its giving error try to execute same function without increamenting const value.

Comment: The return of `test` is not `const`.

Comment: its returning the const.value. can you plz explain why return of test value is not const.?

Comment: Because the return type is not `const`. It is as simple as that. The `const` inside the function is not the same as the value you get from calling the function. You get a non-const copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

'plusplus' operator is (almost) equivalent to '+= 1' that is 'assign the variable its previous value incremented by one'. The value *returned* is not a variable, so it can not be the left-side argument of an assignment. That's why the increment operator is not applicable here. Just do

```
t = test(50) + 1;
```

or

```
t = test(50);
t ++;
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much. Does the local const variable 'b' inside the function make an effect on this problem when it is returned by the type of int?

Comment: The type of variables used inside the function has nothing to do with the issue. The only reason is the return value is not an `lvalue` (see https://www.google.com/#q=define:lvalue) that is it not a variable (a piece of the storage). Similary you can not do '2++' because '2' is a value, not a variable.